# How can I implement variable width look behind regex to get a list of items?

Tags: php, regex, lookbehind

I have a list of items which is prefixed by its type in this case 'fruits' , now I need the list of all fruits and its counts

```
fruits 5 apples, 2 oranges, 3 bananas
```

the regular expression which I am tried

```
(?<=fruits\s)((?<count>\d{1,})\s(?<fruit>\w{1,},))
```

but this gets me the first fruit and its count, but I want list of all fruits with their count, so I tried this

```
(?<=fruits\s((?:\d{1,})\s(?:\w{1,},))*)((?<count>\d{1,})\s(?<fruit>\w{1,},))
```

but I get the error saying that look behinds should be fixed width!

I have tried a sample here: http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/1

Comment: well the starting should be fruits, if I have cars it should fail

    `cars 3 toyota, 4 benz, 1 trabi`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be like this: http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/6, but as mentioned before I should start with 'fruits' only then it should be valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the count from group index 1 and fruit name from group index 2.

```
(?:^fruits|(?<!^)\G)\h*\K(?<count>\d*)\h*(?<fruit>\w*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/7)

Comment: Great! This seems to work but why do you need a negative look-behind before the \G and a non-capturing group instead of \K thus `(?:^fruits|\G)\s((?<count>\d{1,})\s(?<fruit>\w{1,},?))`     http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/25

Comment: thats your wish. You could modify the above according to your needs.

Comment: My question was isn't that simpler or am I missing something?

Comment: \G will match the match boundary, which is either the beginning of the string, or the point where the last character of last match is consumed. In the above case, after `(?:^fruits|(?<!^)\G)`, the marker was set just after to `fruits`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!fruits).*$|((?<count>\d{1,})\s(?<fruit>\w{1,}))
```

Try this.grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/10